# poor mellin transform?

Tags: calculus

$$\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k\left(e^{k\pi}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta\left(s\right)\Gamma\left(s-1\right)\left(-1+2^{2-s}\right)\zeta\left(s-1\right)\pi^{1-s}ds=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}Q\left(s\right)ds.$$
[About Mellin transform and harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126344/about-mellin-transform-and-harmonic-series)
in the above question Marco Cantarini make and interesanting question  the integral residue get the result,
$$\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k\left(e^{k\pi}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{8}\pi-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\right)$$ but the correct result is 
$$\frac{1}{8}\pi-\frac{5}{8}\log\left(2\right).$$ so the integral it is not zero 
I am try to sum using the poles ot the function 
$$\left(c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land z=\frac{2 i \pi  c_1+i \pi }{\pi }\right)\lor z=0$$ ans i realize that miss a term in the the sum
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{k \left(e^{\pi  k}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{8} (\pi -2 \log (4))-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\text{csch}(\pi  (2 k+1))}{2 k+1}$$ corresponding to the poles .
using Mellin transform hidden the poles of the function and only translate the original zero to the poles 1 and o of the transfom function
what to you thing about?.
XE $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{k^3 \left(e^{\pi  k}+1\right)}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\text{csch}(\pi  (2 k+1))}{(2 k+1)^3}+\frac{1}{96} \left(\pi ^3-36 \zeta (3)\right)$$